# Concatenate sparse matrix Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have two sparse matrices in Eigen, and I would like to join them vertically into one. As an example the target of the code would be:

```
SparseMatrix<double> matrix1;
matrix1.resize(10, 10);
SparseMatrix<double> matrix2;
matrix2.resize(5, 10);

SparseMatrix<double> MATRIX_JOIN;
MATRIX_JOIN.resize(15, 10);
MATRIX_JOIN << matrix1, matrix2;
```

I found some solutions on a [forum](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=106944) however, I wasn't able to implement it.

What's the proper way to join the matrices vertically?

**Edit**

My implementation:

```
SparseMatrix<double> L;
SparseMatrix<double> C;
// ... (Operations with the matrices)
SparseMatrix<double> EMATRIX;
EMATRIX.resize(L.rows() + C.rows(), L.cols());
EMATRIX.middleRows(0, L.rows()) = L;
EMATRIX.middleRows(L.rows(), C.rows()) = C;
```

I get an error of types, acording to the compiler the right hand side is an Eigen::Block and the left side is Eigen::SparseMatrix

Comment: What does "I wasn't able to implement it." mean?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I wasn't able to implement the solution that I found in the forum. It was also meant to join (the solution in the forum) a sparse and a dense matrix

Comment: Repeating the same words doesn't explain what the words mean. Please show exactly what you did and what happens when you compile and run the code you wrote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is currently no built-in solution. You can be way more efficient than your solution by using [the internal `insertBack` function](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/3.4.0/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrix.h?ref_type=tags#L376):

```
SparseMatrix<double> M(L.rows() + C.rows(), L.cols());
M.reserve(L.nonZeros() + C.nonZeros());
for(Index c=0; c<L.cols(); ++c)
{
    M.startVec(c); // Important: Must be called once for each column before inserting!
    for(SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator itL(L, c); itL; ++itL)
         M.insertBack(itL.row(), c) = itL.value();
    for(SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator itC(C, c); itC; ++itC)
         M.insertBack(itC.row()+L.rows(), c) = itC.value();
}
M.finalize();
```

Comment: Is this more efficient than using triplets?

Comment: @Javier it should be in all but very weird cases. It may not matter much in many cases.

Comment: @Pippo Thanks for fixing that mistake. I noticed another one (I actually never tested this code)

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Javier's answer.

- Fixed the number of columns in the output matrix (just `cols` instead of `cols+cols`)
- Fixed the lower matrice's triplet indices (`upper.rows() + it.row()` instead of just `it.row()`)

```
using sparse_matrix_type = Eigen::SparseMatrix<T>;
using triplet_type = Eigen::Triplet<T, size_t>;

static sparse_matrix_type sparse_vstack(sparse_matrix_type const& upper, sparse_matrix_type const& lower) {
  assert(upper.cols() == lower.cols() && "vstack with mismatching number of columns");

  std::vector<triplet_type> triplets;
  triplets.reserve(upper.nonZeros() + lower.nonZeros());

  for (int k = 0; k < upper.outerSize(); ++k) {
    for (sparse_matrix_type::InnerIterator it(upper, k); it; ++it) {
      triplets.emplace_back(it.row(), it.col(), it.value());
    }
  }

  for (int k = 0; k < lower.outerSize(); ++k) {
    for (sparse_matrix_type::InnerIterator it(lower, k); it; ++it) {
      triplets.emplace_back(upper.rows() + it.row(), it.col(), it.value());
    }
  }

  sparse_matrix_type result(lower.rows() + upper.rows(), upper.cols());
  result.setFromTriplets(triplets.begin(), triplets.end());
  return result;
}
```

Unfortunately I coulnd't get @chtz's example to work with Eigen 3.3.4 due to a static assertion error `THIS_SPARSE_BLOCK_SUBEXPRESSION_IS_READ_ONLY`. It seems to be explicitly forbidden by Eigen (see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/SparseBlock_8h_source.html).

Comment: I think you still have a bug here: When you create `result`, `upper.rows() + upper.rows()` should be `upper.rows() + lower.rows()` I think.

Comment: There is no `block` of any kind in my solution. Did you mean the attempt by @Javier in his question? That does indeed not work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following:

```
MATRIX_JOIN.resize(matrix1.rows() + matrix2.rows(), matrix1.cols() + matrix2.cols());
MATRIX_JOIN.setZero();

// Fill MATRIX_JOIN with triples from the other matrices
std::vector<Triplet<double> > tripletList;
for (int k = 0; k < matrix1.outerSize(); ++k)
{
    for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(matrix1, k); it; ++it)
    {
        tripletList.push_back(Triplet<double>(it.row(), it.col(), it.value()));
    }
}
for (int k = 0; k < matrix2.outerSize(); ++k)
{
    for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(matrix2, k); it; ++it)
    {
        tripletList.push_back(Triplet<double>(it.row(), it.col(), it.value()));
    }
}
FINALMATRIX.setFromTriplets(tripletList.begin(), tripletList.end());
```

There can be a speedup by calling `tripleList.reserve(X)` with X being the expected amount of triplets to insert.