# How would you merge sparse matrices to create a new sparse matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen3, intel-mkl

I'm trying to achieve the following thing:

```
Given A(m,n), B(m,q), C(p,n), D(p,q), sparse matrices.
Create E(m+p,n+q), a sparse matrix, like :
E = | A B |
    | C D |
```

I tried the following :

- Eigen - the only way I found to achieve this was reading all non zeroes values from A, B, C and D, store it in a `std::vector<Triplet>`, and construct E with `setFromTriplets`. This is way too complex.
- Intel MKL - the algorithm was the same, except I was using Block Sparse Row storage representation. First, read non zeroes then call a constructor. Same complexity, not usable.

The problem with these libraries is that E is construct just like any sparse matrice, without using the fact that there are redundancies between parts of E and A,B,C,D. I suppose that it should be possible to construct E just by reindexing what's store in the internal structures of A,B,C and D.

The question is the following : how would you achieve this merging operation with sparse matrices? Which software would you use? Which algorithm would you use?

The ideal solution would not use a block storage scheme so that sparsity would be based on zero values, not zero blocks.

Programming language doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with `E`? If you just want to multiply vectors/matrices with it, you could achieve this without ever explicitly composing it (`(E*x).head(m) == A*x.head(n) + B*x.tail(q);`, etc) -- if you actually want to store `E` in CCS you will need to iterate through all submatrices. Related question regarding concatenation with Eigen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756428/concatenate-sparse-matrix-eigen

Comment: Actually yeah, I just want to multiply E with matrices. However, E can also be used to create an other matrix, let's say E' = [E,F;G,H], and, in that case, I suppose there is no workaround beside constructing E?

Comment: In theory, that approach can be done recursively. At least with Eigen this currently would need to be done manually (there is a related feature-request here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1433)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, new solution! It seems like everybody has figured out a way to do this by creating a new container of triplets, and adding accordingly. This is admittedly safe and intuitive, but not so fast even if you reserve the nonzeros accordingly.

In this approach, which works only on column-major matrices (you could make row-major verisons quite easily), I work directly with the CSC data structure. I present 3 methods: **1) "vertically stacking"** two sparse matrices with the same number of columns, **2) "horizontally stacking"** two sparse matrices with the same number of rows, and 3) **"in-place horizontally stacking"** two sparse matrices with the same number of rows. 3) is inherently more efficient because the storage of the left matrix is unchanged.

As you can see, horizontally stacking two matrices is almost trivial even when working directly with the raw pointers. Vertically stacking requires a bit of thinking, but not much. If anyone can figure out an in-place method for vertically stacking that avoids some copying (or any improvement), please let me know!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

template<typename Scalar, typename StorageIndex>
void sparse_stack_v(
    const SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& top,
    const SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& bottom,
    SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& stacked)
{
    assert(top.cols() == bottom.cols());
    stacked.resize(top.rows() + bottom.rows(), top.cols());
    stacked.resizeNonZeros(top.nonZeros() + bottom.nonZeros());

    StorageIndex i = 0;

    for (StorageIndex col = 0; col < top.cols(); col++)
    {
        stacked.outerIndexPtr()[col] = i;

        for (StorageIndex j = top.outerIndexPtr()[col]; j < top.outerIndexPtr()[col + 1]; j++, i++)
        {
            stacked.innerIndexPtr()[i] = top.innerIndexPtr()[j];
            stacked.valuePtr()[i] = top.valuePtr()[j];
        }

        for (StorageIndex j = bottom.outerIndexPtr()[col]; j < bottom.outerIndexPtr()[col + 1]; j++, i++)
        {
            stacked.innerIndexPtr()[i] = (StorageIndex)top.rows() + bottom.innerIndexPtr()[j];
            stacked.valuePtr()[i] = bottom.valuePtr()[j];
        }
    }
    stacked.outerIndexPtr()[top.cols()] = i;
}

template<typename Scalar, typename StorageIndex>
void sparse_stack_h(
    const SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& left,
    const SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& right,
    SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& stacked)
{
    assert(left.rows() == right.rows());

    stacked.resize(left.rows(), left.cols() + right.cols());
    stacked.resizeNonZeros(left.nonZeros() + right.nonZeros());

    std::copy(left.innerIndexPtr(), left.innerIndexPtr() + left.nonZeros(), stacked.innerIndexPtr());
    std::copy(right.innerIndexPtr(), right.innerIndexPtr() + right.nonZeros(), stacked.innerIndexPtr() + left.nonZeros());

    std::copy(left.valuePtr(), left.valuePtr() + left.nonZeros(), stacked.valuePtr());
    std::copy(right.valuePtr(), right.valuePtr() + right.nonZeros(), stacked.valuePtr() + left.nonZeros());

    std::copy(left.outerIndexPtr(), left.outerIndexPtr() + left.cols(), stacked.outerIndexPtr());//dont need the last entry of A.outerIndexPtr() -- total length is AB.cols() + 1 = A.cols() + B.cols() + 1
    std::transform(right.outerIndexPtr(), right.outerIndexPtr() + right.cols() + 1, stacked.outerIndexPtr() + left.cols(), [&](StorageIndex i) { return i + left.nonZeros(); });
}

template<typename Scalar, typename StorageIndex>
void sparse_stack_h_inplace(
    SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& left,
    const SparseMatrix<Scalar, ColMajor, StorageIndex>& right)
{
    assert(left.rows() == right.rows());

    const StorageIndex leftcol = (StorageIndex)left.cols();
    const StorageIndex leftnz = (StorageIndex)left.nonZeros();

    left.conservativeResize(left.rows(), left.cols() + right.cols());
    left.resizeNonZeros(left.nonZeros() + right.nonZeros());

    std::copy(right.innerIndexPtr(), right.innerIndexPtr() + right.nonZeros(), left.innerIndexPtr() + leftnz);
    std::copy(right.valuePtr(), right.valuePtr() + right.nonZeros(), left.valuePtr() + leftnz);
    std::transform(right.outerIndexPtr(), right.outerIndexPtr() + right.cols() + 1, left.outerIndexPtr() + leftcol, [&](StorageIndex i) { return i + leftnz; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Octave 7, you can just join using standard matrix notation:

```
>> E = [A,B;C,D];
```

As a test:

```
>> x = sparse(2,3)
x = Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 2, cols = 3, nnz = 0 [0%])
>> y = sparse(20,3)
y = Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 20, cols = 3, nnz = 0 [0%])
>> x(1,2) = 1
x = Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 2, cols = 3, nnz = 1 [17%])
>> y(10,1)=99
y = Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 20, cols = 3, nnz = 1 [1.7%])
>> [x,x;y,y]
ans =Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 22, cols = 6, nnz = 4 [3%])

  (12, 1) -> 99
  (1, 2) -> 1
  (12, 4) -> 99
  (1, 5) -> 1
```